# Special characters in .htaccess file using regular expression.

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have this pattern to match `?q=user` but every rule that i write in .htaccess will not catch `?` , I assume it treats it as special character. How would I specify to treat `?` as part of string in `.htaccess` file using regular expression.

Comment: Where is the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the escape character `\` before `?`, something like `\?`

Comment: This is what I tried so far RewriteRule (^|/)?q=user(/|$) - [F]